# Parcelable ejecuta dos veces el bloque init en android con kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo una clase personalizada que estoy enviando desde un activity hacia un tabbed activity (fragments) mediante `parcelable`.

En el bloque init de mi custom class ejecuto una función para transformar uno de los valores que llegan al constructor cuando creo mi clase, pero `parcelable` al construir nuevamente el objeto, vuelve a pasar por el init block ejecutando sus funciones de nuevo y dañando mi transformación de valores. ¿Por que sucede esto?

**Enviando los datos de un activity**

```
    val intent = Intent(ctx, resultado_calculadora_requerimientos::class.java)
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putParcelable("requerimientos", requerimientos)
    intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle)
    startActivity(intent)
```

**Pasando los datos a los fragment**

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        var fragment : Fragment? = null
        val bundle :Bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle")
        when(position){
            0 -> fragment = resultado_calculadora_requerimientos_frag1()
            1 -> fragment = resultado_calculadora_requerimientos_frag2()
        }
        fragment!!.arguments = bundle
        return fragment!!
    }
```

** Y cuando llegan a los fragment**

```
if (arguments != null) {
        requerimientos = arguments!!.getParcelable<Parcelable>("requerimientos") as Requerimientos?
    }
```

**La declaración de mi clase**

```
class Requerimientos (
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    var peso: Double                     ,
    private var altura: Double           ,
    private val edad: Int                ,
    private val actividad_fisica: String ,
    private val sexo: String             ,
    val unidad_medida :Int        /* 0 - cm y kg / 1 - lb y in */) : Parcelable {
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readInt(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readInt()) {
    factorAgua  = parcel.readDouble()
    factorProt  = parcel.readDouble()
    factorLip   = parcel.readDouble()
    factorCh    = parcel.readDouble()
}

init{
    if (unidad_medida == 1){
        this.peso   = this.lbAkg(this.peso)
        this.altura = this.inAcm(altura)
        Log.d("waskjas", "Cambiando los valores de peso y altura a cm y kg")
        Log.d("waskjas", "valor peso: $peso")
        Log.d("waskjas", "valor altura: $altura")
    }
}
```

Comment: Debes instanciar en ambos activitys la clase y pasarla en el bundle mediante parcelable.